# Поставьте запятые в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Полина вышла к гостям на веранду и пока дамы восторженно восхищались её изящным нарядом она думала о том как хорошо было бы оказаться вдалеке от этой надоевшей суеты.*

Answer (score 3):

"Полина вышла к гостям на веранду, и, пока дамы восторженно восхищались её изящным нарядом, она думала о том, как хорошо было бы оказаться вдалеке от этой надоевшей суеты."

Первая запятая (перед "и") -- необходима: здесь [сложносочинённая связь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BF.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B2_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B8).

Answer (score 0):

> **Полина вышла к гостям на открытую веранду,(1) и,(2) пока дамы восторженно выражали восхищение её изящным нарядом,(3) она думала о том,(4) как хорошо было бы оказаться вдалеке от этой надоевшей пустой суеты.**
>   Запятая (1) разделяет предложения «Полина вышла к гостям на открытую веранду» и «она думала о том».
>       Запятые (2) и (3) выделяют придаточную часть «пока дамы восторженно выражали восхищение её изящным нарядом» (запятая (2) ставится, т.к. у союза ПОКА нет второй части - ТО).
>       Запятая (4) отделяет придаточную часть «как хорошо было бы оказаться вдалеке от этой надоевшей пустой суеты».

([Тривиум](http://gordeevaln.ru/question/multichoice/3888))